# Was there any discussion about Israel during the APEC meeting between China and the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, china, israel

> U.S. and China's militaries have had a number of near-misses and
> acrimonious exchanges over the past year. After the pledge to renew
> communications, U.S. Secretary of Defense Lloyd Austin will meet his
> Chinese counterpart when that person is named, a senior U.S. official
> said.
>
> Biden and Xi agreed China would stem the export of items related to
> the production of the opioid fentanyl, a leading cause of drug
> overdoses in the United States. "It’s going to save lives,” Biden
> said, adding he appreciated Xi’s “commitment” on the issue.
>
> Under the agreement, China will go directly after specific chemical
> companies that make fentanyl precursors, a senior U.S. official told
> reporters. He vowed to "trust but verify" Chinese actions on the drug.
>
> The two leaders also agreed to get experts together to discuss the
> risks of artificial intelligence.
>
> A U.S. official described an exchange over Taiwan, the democratic
> island that China claims as its territory. China's preference is for
> peaceful reunification with the Chinese-claimed island of Taiwan, Xi
> told Biden, the U.S. official said, but Xi went on to talk about
> conditions in which force could be used.

https://www.reuters.com/world/biden-xi-meet-us-china-military-economic-tensions-grind-2023-11-15/

I know there were discussion about military cooperation and cooperation on the substance control, but I surprisingly didn't hear anything about Israel. Was there any discussion about it according to the public domain? I am guessing the U.S. didn't expect anything from China on Israel since China made it pretty clear it will side with the Global South.